# calculation of normal derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded region in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Suppose $u$ is a smooth function in $\Omega$. I want to calculate
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}|\nabla u|^2\mbox{ on }\partial\Omega,$$
the normal derivative with respect to the outward unit normal $\nu$.
Here is my calculation: 
$$\tag{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}|\nabla u|^2=\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}
\left\langle\nabla u,\nabla u\right\rangle=2\left\langle\nabla \frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu},\nabla u\right\rangle.$$
But I am sure this is wrong, because I can obtain an absurd conclusion by assuming that $u$ is the first Steklov eigenfunction. So I would like to ask where my mistake is in $(1)$. My guess is that I may have to add a term related to geodesic curvature in $(1)$.

Comment: Can you explain the absurdity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you've commuted the normal derivative with the gradient. Your notation makes this seem fair game, since you can commute partial derivatives; but the normal derivative isn't a partial derivative! Just carefully compute in Cartesian coordinates:

$$\frac12 \nu^i \partial_i (u_j u_j) = u_j \nu^i u_{ji}=u_j \partial_j(\nu^i u_i) - u_j u_i \partial_j \nu^i;$$

so the term you're missing is $-\langle D_{\nabla u}\nu,\nabla u\rangle$. This is indeed a curvature term - it's $A(\nabla u, \nabla u)$ for $A$ the second fundamental form of $\partial \Omega$. In the plane-curve case this should reduce to something like $$k \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \ell}\right)^2$$ for $\ell$ a unit-speed coordinate on $\partial \Omega$.